# Selecting counties with a river

Tags: qgis

I want to select counties along a river. The following picture is an output image by using the Ohio River. The river vector is a line or a buffered area. Now, I choose "Edit" and "Select Features" by hand. I would use "Select by Expression." But I don't know how to write "Expression" in two layers.

[image]

Comment: Use 'Select by Location'  in Vector>Research Tools>Select by Location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the solution in comment from @Mapperz, you can use something like this as an expression in select by expression:

```
touches( $geometry,
geometry(get_feature('river_layer','rivername', 'Ohio River')))
```

Please, be aware that expressions are case sensitive.